# Mac Terminal Prompt of iTerm with Oh-my-Z is messed up

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I'm not sure exactly what I did besides try to uninstall an application but it seems my prompt is not working. I just want my iTerm 2 back to the way it was...

Here is my `.zshrc` file and the prompt. It looks bad. How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using *Oh-My-ZSH*. In that case you should be able to restore at least the default settings with:

```
cp $HOME/.oh-my-zsh/templates/zshrc.zsh-template $HOME/.zshrc
```

This will of course overwrite your `~/.zshrc`, but the first line is in the template anyway and the second line is a `bash`-styile definition for the shell prompt and has no place in a `zsh` configuration file.

After copying the template I would suggest having a look into the new `~/.zshrc` to see, if there are any other settings you want to make.

---

If the `cp` command fails because it cannot find the source file, then you probably have somehow removed *Oh-My-ZSH*. In that case you can re-install it by following the instructions on [OhMyZ.sh](http://ohmyz.sh).